# how do I import Mayavi to my Python code in PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, mayavi

I wrote a bit of code and happened to use Mayavi library. However, after I executed,

```
ImportError: No module named mayavi
```

has shown from

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
```

. I did a little bit of research but none of them could fix my problem.

I am using Windows7 and Python2.7.6.

Any help will be appreciated.

Lastly, I also tried enthought but it does not work on my machine.

Comment: How did you install `mayavi`? Did you install it for the correct version of the interpreter? Are you using a virtual environment for your project? Did you check that the `mayavi` package is indeed in one of the directories listed in `sys.path`?

Comment: @Bakuriu That is what I'm not sure. Any site/blog which can walk me through?

Comment: Open a python terminal and type: `import sys;print(sys.argv)`. You should see a list of directories. Open the file manager and search in the listed directories for the mayavi package. If you can't find it, then it means you didn't install it correctly.

Comment: @Bakuriu This is what's printed.`['-c', '-f', 'C:\\Users\\XXX\\Documents\\.ipython\\profile_default\\security\\kernel-2088.json', '--pylab=inline', '--ConsoleWidget.font_size=11', "--IPKernelApp.parent_appname='ipython-qtconsole'", '--interrupt=964', '--parent=960']`. What am I looking for?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was probably distracted when I typed that comment. It's `sys.path` that you should check, not `sys.argv` :s

Comment: @Bakuriu This is the result. `['', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Orange\\orng', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-3.0-msw']`

Comment: @Bakuriu BTW, I managed to run it on IPython QTConsole on Anaconda but not any other console. So, I apparently have my code run; however, I don't have any editor to use. One more thing tho, just found out that a lots of packages can be downloaded in PyCharm including Mayavi through setting window. It fails to install, nonetheless due to inconsistency of version, sadly. Anyways, I thank you for your time but not sure if you want to continue on.

Comment: I am not familiar with pycharm but any sane IDE should allow you to specify the path of the python distribution that it uses, which ostensibly is wherever you have anaconda installed.

Comment: @aestrivex Thank you. That's a very brilliant idea. Done it and it's working.